# How to concatenate bytes together

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct, byte

Here is the code snippet:-

```
join_values = []
new_byteArray = [128, 0, 0, 0, 86, 70, 124, -96]
for values in byteArray:
    values = long(values)
    store_values = struct.pack('!q', values)
    join_values.append(store_values)
print join_values
```

This produces correct result which is:-

```
['\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80',
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00V', 
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00F', 
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00|', 
 '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xa0']
```

This result is correct but isn't there any way I can do a combine pack or do something so that the last out of 8 bytes concatenate together so that I can get the output as:-

```
\x80\x00\x00x00VF|\xa0
```

Comment: is there a typo in your desired output? Shouldn't it be `\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00V\x00F\x00|\xa0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get the last byte from a string `s` by using `s[-1]`.

python2.7 has a feature called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which can be used to perform a transformation on each element of a list.

Finally, [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the strings together.

Putting that all together would look something like

```
my_transformed_list = [s[-1] for s in join_values]
concatenated = ''.join(my_transformed_list)
```

---

Another way to solve this would be with functional programming. The act of performing a transformation on every element of a list is called a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
my_transformed_list2 = map(lambda s: s[-1], j)
concatenated2 = ''.join(my_transformed_list2)
```